# How to store and retrieve 3-Bit number via bitmask?

Tags: c++, bitmask

Lets say I have a bitmask

```
enum ExampleMask
{       
   Attribute1 = 1 << 1,
   Attribute2 = 1 << 2,
   ...
   Attribute27 = 1 << 27
}
```

So I already use 27 of my 32 available bits.

I now want to be able to also store and retrieve a 3 bit unsigned integer in addition to the flags using the bitmask.

For example:

```
// Storing values
int mask =  Attribute2 | Attribute6 | Attribute18; // Saving some attributes
int mask |= ???? // How to save the number 8?

// Retrieving values
if(mask & Attribute2) do something...;
if(mask & Attribute6) do something...;
int storedValue =  ???? // How to retrieve the 8?
```

Basically I want to reserve 3 bits in my bitmask to save a number between 0-8 in there

Thank you for taking time to read and help.

Comment: I need to be able to store flags as normal in addition to saving the 9

Comment: you're right, I mean 8

Comment: It's OK though because you actually have 4 spare bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just shift the value up into the unused bits, e.g.

To store the value:

```
mask |= val << 28;
```

To retrieve the value:

```
val = mask >> 28;
```

Note that `mask` should really be `unsigned` to avoid propagating the sign bit when shifting. If you have to use a signed int for some reason then you should add an additional masking operation when retrieving `val`, e.g.

```
val = (mask >> 28) & 0x0f;
```

Comment: `mask` and `val` are signed though. Shouldn't they be unsigned integers in order to avoid UB?

Comment: You'd also need to change the type to `unsigned` (or, more portably, `uint32_t`).

Comment: I was just editing the answer to cover the issue with signed int - for  a 3 bit value it doesn't matter but it appears the OP actually wants 4 bits so I've added a note about masking or using unsigned int.

Comment: `val = mask >> 28` can be a problem if there are even more bits beyond the three (or four) relevant bits. I would suggest to use `val = (mask >> 28) % 8`, or: `val = (mask >> Attribute28) % (1<<3)`